# Локализация WPF-приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, локализация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить локализацию WPF-приложения?


Ни разу до этого не приходилось писать многоязыковые приложения. Локализацию строк интерфейса сделал по этой статье [Локализация WPF приложений на лету](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256193/).

Но еще необходимо сделать перевод строк, которые выдает приложение в случае ошибки или как подсказка пользователю. Например, пользователь выбирает файл неправильного формата и получает сообщение в зависимости от выбранного языка.

Comment: Делается локализация точно так же, все текстовки из кода уходят в resx файлы, а в коде вместо текстовок используется ссылка на ресурс соответствующий.

Comment: @Monk приведите примеры кода, пожалуйста. Все что я находил - это какие-то урывки исходных кодов. А примеры на msdn вообще тихий ужас... Также хочется, чтобы при использовании resx-файлов не создавались дополнительные библиотеки (ru-RU.dll, en-US.dll и тд).

Comment: Поторопился насчет так же, по ссылке статья довольно специфическая. Завтра уж, если не забуду и никто не напишет, отпишу.

Comment: @badc0de32 а чем вам доп. библиотеки помешали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хочу, чтобы была только одна сборка. Планируется, что программа будет передаваться между коллегами и не хочется создавать зависимостей.

Comment: Хорошая, правильная локализация — это **огромный** проект. Я вот недавно занимался, кода реально много. Особенно большая проблема во внешней инфраструктуре: как поддерживать в хорошем состоянии базу данных переводов. Плюс если хотите переключение языка на лету, придётся хорошо попотеть. Локализация через `ResourceDictionary` и доступ через `DynamicResource` — правильная идея. Но много неприятностей доставляют составные строки (`"Should {filename} be deleted?"` -> `"Нужно ли удалять {filename}?"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нормальная локализация в C# представлена одним единственным способом - `resx` файлы.

Для небольших проектов можно просто включить ресурсы, открываем свойства проекта и пользуемся:

[image: Resources in project]

В проекте при этом создается resx файл с локализацией по умолчанию. Чтобы добавить ещё одну - достаточно создать (Add -> New Item -> resx) ещё один файл, дополнив имя культурой (`Resources.{culture}.resx`)

[image: Project resx files]

В коде просто пишем обращение к ресурсу:

`Console.WriteLine(Resources.Example);`

Для смены языка приложения принудительно достаточно поменять `CurrentUICulture`.

Теперь по поводу дополнительных сборок.
Хороших решений тут нет, простота выше описанного решения теряется, как только вы пытаетесь сделать шаг влево\вправо.
Более менее рабочее решение описано [тут (enSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1821352/3768545), но оно жутко неудобное в использовании.
Как можно заметить, простота использования вида `Console.WriteLine(Resources.Example);` теряется и обращения происходят уже вручную. Это можно автоматизировать, но тогда уже лучше вместо стандартного генератора посмотреть в сторону шаблонов (для общего представления можно глянуть [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx)).

Т.е. чтобы сделать всё в одной сборке вам придётся написать замену стандартной схеме сборки ресурсов. Стоит ли оно того - решайте сами. Если интересны варианты с шаблонами - лучше изучите вопрос и задавайте вопросы отдельно, готовое решение так не видел, самописные в разных организациях - попадались.

В дополнение, как совет по поводу:

> Планируется, что программа будет передаваться между коллегами и не
>   хочется создавать зависимостей.

Есть click-once, хоть он и очень неудачный на мой взгляд. Но, никаких заморочек по зависимостям и куче сборок не будет.